# Laravel multidimensional array not counting results

Tags: arrays, laravel, model-view-controller, multidimensional-array, eloquent

i have problem in league standings. Teams have more than one match, but the results show only one. So results in the array are not counted.

for exmpl:

First team have played more than one match, but array shows just one , array:

```
array:10 [▼
  "firstTeam" => array:6 [▼
    "points" => 3
    "scoredGoals" => 3
    "goalsConceded" => 1
    "wins" => 1
    "loses" => 0
    "draws" => 0
  ]
  "secondTeam" => & array:6 [▶]
  "thirdTeam" => array:6 [▶]
  "fourthTeam" => array:6 [▶]
  "fifthTeam" => array:6 [▶]
  "sixthTeam" => array:6 [▶]
  "seventhTeam" => & array:6 [▶]
  "eighthTeam" => array:6 [▶]
  "ninthTeam" => & array:6 [▶]
  "tenthTeam" => array:6 [▶]
]
```

matches:
[image]

help with this results counting.

My Controller:

```
    foreach ($matches as $match) {

        $homeTeamScore = $match->score->home_team_score;
        $awayTeamScore = $match->score->away_team_score;

        $standings[$match->homeTeam->name] = $blank;
        $standings[$match->awayTeam->name] = $blank;

        $home = &$standings[$match->homeTeam->name];
        $away = &$standings[$match->awayTeam->name];

        $away['scoredGoals'] += $awayTeamScore;
        $home['scoredGoals'] += $homeTeamScore;
        $away['goalsConceded'] += $homeTeamScore;
        $home['goalsConceded'] += $awayTeamScore;
        switch ($homeTeamScore <=> $awayTeamScore) {
            case -1:
                // home lost
                // swap home and away and let it fall through
                $tmpHome = &$home;
                $home = &$away;
                $away = &$tmpHome;
            case 1:
                // home won
                $home['points'] += 3;
                $home['wins']++;
                $away['loses']++;
                break;
            default:
                // draw
                $home['points']++;
                $away['points']++;
                $home['draws']++;
                $away['draws']++;
        }
    }
```

standings:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: [fetch-additional-data-in-to-array-from-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65255578/fetch-additional-data-in-to-array-from-database) here is described releations

Comment: you are resetting the teams information in the standings array to the blank value every iteration of that loop: `$standings[$match->homeTeam->name] = $blank;` ... so any team can't have more information than 1 match since you keep overwriting it

Comment: so what should be instead of:                                                                                     $standings[$match->homeTeam->name] = $blank; @lagbox

Comment: sorry, i can not see where "@lagbox

Comment: $standings[$match->homeTeam->name] ??= $blank;
 $standings[$match->awayTeam->name] ??= $blank;      if you mean this, it doesn't help, getting error  @lagbox

Comment: okay then adjust for the error

Comment: please, need heelp here, which operator is needed here? @lagbox

Comment: can you help me @lagbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop overwriting the team's standings array on every iteration. If you want to adjust the previous code you can adjust what is below:

This:

```
$standings[$match->homeTeam->name] ??= $blank;
$standings[$match->awayTeam->name] ??= $blank;
```

Is:

```
if (! isset($standings[$match->homeTeam->name])) {
    $standings[$match->homeTeam->name] = $blank;
}

if (! isset($standings[$match->awayTeam->name])) {
    $standings[$match->awayTeam->name] = $blank;
}
```

`??=` is an operator from PHP 7.4 so you are probably using a lower version of PHP.

Comment: no problem, just make sure to take some time and understand what all that does

Comment: maybe you can help me with this little bit? standings are only with teams, which have added results, but i need that teams without added results should be with 0 value on points,games and etc